# Definition of power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

In textbook, the power series is defined as:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_n}{(x-a)^n}$$

But for some series classified as power series, the power of $(x-a)$ is not $n$. For example, in the Bessel function of order $0$, the power of $x$ is $2n$.

My question:
Is there any limitation for the power of $(x-a)$ except that it must be a positive integer?

For exmaple, are the following series power series?
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_n}{(x-a)^{n^2}}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_n}{(x-a)^{2^n}}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_n}{(x-a)^{n!}}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_n}{(x-a)^{n^n}}$$

Comment: Of course they are all power series - for example: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_n}{(x-a)^{n^2}}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{d_m}{(x-a)^{m}}$ where $d_m=0, m \ne n^2, d_m=c_n, m=n^2$ and same for all the others

Comment: $n$ doesn't even have to be positive: take a look at Laurent Series ( https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaurentSeries.html )

Comment: You need to check the powers are non-negative integers: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_n}{(x-a)^{\sqrt n}}$ would fail

Comment: @postmortes Wiki said Laurent series is not power series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series

Comment: @lovetl2002 Wikipedia is not a reliable source of information (hence why I didn't link to it), but actually Wikipedia's page on Laurent series (linked to at the bottom of your link) *does* start off noting that Laurent series are generalised power series -- i.e. a Laurent series can do anything a power series can do *and more*.  By all means, distinguish power series as being Laurent series with no negative powers, but it's helpful to have the full picture :)